# Python str slicing out of list

Tags: python, object-slicing

I would write a little function to check if a string in a list, and when yes, the string should remove out of the List.

this is my code

```
def str_clearer(L):
    for i in L:
        if i == str:
            L.remove(i)
        else:
            pass
    print(L)
    return L

L = [1, 2, 3, "hallo", "4", 3.3]

str_clearer(L)

assert str_clearer(L) == [1, 2, 3, 3.3]
```

but it make nothing with the List.
if i make it so that it make a new List with all int or float, he make same nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Python built-in function, [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), can be used here.

The following approach is similar to yours.

```
In[0]: def remove_str(your_list):
           new_list = []    
           for element in your_list:
           if not(isinstance(element, str)):
               new_list.append(element)
           return new_list

In[1]: remove_str([1, 2, 3, "hallo", "4", 3.3])
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 3.3]
```

This can be much shorter, though.

```
In[2]: mylist = [1, 2, 3, "hallo", "4", 3.3]
In[3]: result = [x for x in mylist if not(isinstance(x, str))]
In[4]: print(result)
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 3.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Type checking can be done with `isinstance`. This could actually be done pretty elegantly in a list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in L if not isinstance(x, str)]
```